# Twitter Bootstrap textboxes size limit

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I'm using bootstrap text boxes as :

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
      <p>
         <label>Contact List</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="list" name="list">
             <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-10">
      <p>
        <input class="form-control" id="contact_id" maxlength="3" size="4" name="contact_id">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="load_contact">Load Contact</button>
     </p>
 </div>
```

I would like to align textbox and button at the right side of dropdownlist, but currently textbox is aligned through out the page.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bootstrap use a **12 columns based row**...*

*You have (for large view : col-lg) 14 columns ( col-lg-4 + col-lg-10 )*

*So just **modify this to have a sum of 12** ( 4 + 8 ) ( I changed to col-xs for see it a xtra small )*

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>
         <label>Contact List</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="list" name="list">
             <option value="">Please Select</option>
          </select>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <p>
        <input class="form-control" id="contact_id" maxlength="3" size="4" name="contact_id">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="load_contact">Load Contact</button>
     </p>
 </div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/jIpiycwlRU)

Comment: But it still displays a large textbox. Text always have 2 letter id to insert, so need a small sized textbox. and also the layout format will be - <list ><text box><loadbutton>

Comment: yes it is. for small textbox, I have given col-xs-1. Thanks Yenne. +1 and accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

please change  `col-lg-10` to `col-lg-8`